# CPU throttled to 0.78 GHz when using MacsFanControl on Windows

Tags: windows, cpu, temperature

Sometimes I need to run Windows via Bootcamp on my MBP 16". In Windows, the fans of the notebook always spin at maximum speed, so I tried regulate them using "MacsFanControl".

When using a sensor based logic (e.g. CPU PECI with 60 °C lower and 85 °C upper limit), the CPU will throttle after a few minutes to 0.78 GHz due to high temperatures of the CPU. I am yet to discover a working configuration by trial and error yet.

Did anyone achieve a working configuration for MacsFanControl on Windows that throttles the fans but not the CPU base frequency?

Comment: You're basically asking for a cooler CPU without using the fans, which is impossible.

Comment: @benwiggy: No - on macOS, the fans run on a low speed in idle and fast speed when needed. I need a configuration fo MacsFanControl which replicates this behavior on Windows as well.